# Why does aggregate NOT ignore NA values as per documentation?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Suppose I have the following data.frame:

```
v <- data.frame(user=c("tom", "tom", "joe", "joe", "pat"), grade=c(70, NA, 80, 90, 100), stringsAsFactors = F)
v
  user grade
1  tom    70
2  tom    NA
3  joe    80
4  joe    90
5  pat   100
```

Suppose I would like to aggregate by user as follows:

```
aggregate(v$grade, by=list(user = v$user), FUN=sum)
  user   x
1  joe 170
2  pat 100
3  tom  NA
```

I am perplexed why "tom" comes out as `NA` because in the documentation for `aggregate?` it says:

> na.action
>   a function which indicates what should happen when the data
>   contain NA values. The default is to ignore missing values in the
>   given variables.

Am I misunderstanding what `na.action` is saying because it leads me to believe that it should ignore `NA` values?

Comment: `aggregate(v$grade, by=list(user = v$user), FUN=sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: `na.rm` is not a listed argument in the documentation for this function but your solution does work. What gives?

Comment: It is from `sum`. There are two function arguments.  -1) from `aggregate` itself where the `na.action` happens

Comment: so why is `na.action` not working? According to documentation for `aggregate` the function: `sum` should never see `NA`

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` gets passed to `FUN` via the `...` arguments, so you are doing `sum(something, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong S3 method. The default method does not have an `na.action` parameter. Use the formula method, which has it:

```
aggregate(grade ~ user, v, sum)
#  user grade
#1  joe   170
#2  pat   100
#3  tom    70
```

The S3 methods and their parameters are documented on the help page. The formula method is the only one with this parameter and to my knowledge it is not called internally by other methods.

Comment: ohhhh,. I see, I didn't read the "Usage" part very carefully. I see, different S3 methods of different classes use different args. Damn, that's confusing!

Comment: what would be the aggregate formula if you wanted to aggregate 2 fields like: low_grade and high_grade by user. Would it be `cbind(low_grade, high_grade) ~ user`? Is there more documentation on aggregate formulas somewhere?

Comment: The same as when using `lm` with two dependent variables: `cbind(low_grade, high_grade) ~ user`

Comment: Btw., `aggregate` is not used very much anymore since people have mostly switched to using the dplyr or data.table packages for aggregation.